# Sum minimum of corresponding column values

Tags: excel, excel-formula, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have two columns with numbers. I would like to calculate in a separate cell a sum. The sum will include the minimums of corresponding cells in these two columns.

Example:

```
        A  |  B
       --------
[1]     1  |  2
[2]     4  |  3
[3]     0  |  1
[4]     5  |  5
```

I need a formula that would calculate in a cell the sum of 1 + 3 + 0 + 5 where

```
* 1 is the MIN(A1,B1), 
* 3 is the MIN(A2,B2) 
* 0 is the MIN(A3,B3)
* 5 is the MIN(A4,B4)
```

Is that possible in a single formula (independent of #rows)?

Working with LibreOffice Calc at the moment, but Excel solutions more than welcome.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an **array formula** (doc for [Libre Office](https://help.libreoffice.org/Calc/Array_Functions#Creating_Array_Formulas) and for [Excel](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-HA010342564.aspx)) for this:

```
=SUM(IF(A1:A4<B1:B4, A1:A4, B1:B4))
```

Confirm by `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` instead of simple Enter.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can do this with a formula but it's not very scalable. For example, you can do this:

```
=SUM(MIN(A1:B1),MIN(A2:B2),MIN(A3:B3), MIN(A4:B4))
```

that will work in the case you described. However, I appreciate that if you have a large number of rows then this won't scale nicely. In that case, I think you'll need a VBA macro as I can't see a way to do this. I'm prepared to be corrected though by some Excel formula guru.

For a VBA solution, you can try the following (found in the [OzGrid forums](http://www.ozgrid.com/forum/showthread.php?t=70352)):

```vb
Function sumOfMax(ByVal inputRange As Range, Optional doMin As Boolean) As Double
    Dim inRRay As Variant
    Dim currentMax As Double
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set inputRange = Application.Intersect(inputRange, inputRange.Parent.UsedRange)
    If Nothing Is inputRange Then Exit Function
    inRRay = inputRange.Value
    For i = 1 To UBound(inRRay, 1)
        currentMax = Val(inRRay(i, 1))
        For j = 1 To UBound(inRRay, 2)
            If (Val(inRRay(i, j)) > currentMax) Xor doMin Then currentMax = Val(inRRay(i, j))
        Next j
        sumOfMax = sumOfMax + currentMax
    Next i
End Function
```

When set to `TRUE`, the optional parameter calculates the minimums as opposed to the maximums that this macro calculates by default. In your example, you would need to call it like this:

```
=sumOfMax(A1:B4, TRUE)
```

Just remember you need to place the code in a standard code module.

Comment: does LibreOffice support VBA?

Comment: @Aprillion: No, I don't think so, but he did say in his question: *"Excel solutions more than welcome"*.